# Conditional Incremental builds in Nextjs

Tags: caching, next.js, incremental-build

#### Context

I am learning Nextjs which is a framework for developing react applications quickly by providing many functionalities out of the box such as Server Side Rendering, Fast Refresh and many others out of the box without any configuration. It also provides a functionality to optionally generate some web pages statically which are pre rendered at build time instead of rendering on demand. It achieves it by querying the data required for the page at build time. Nextjs also provides an optional argument expressed in seconds after which the data is re queried and  the page re rendered. All of it happens on page level rather than rebuilding the entire website.

#### Problems

1. We cannot know in advance how frequently data would change, the data may change after 1 second or 10 minutes and it is impossible to know in advance and extremely hard to predict. However, it is most certainly not a constant number of seconds.  With this approach, I might show outdated information due to higher time limit or I might end up querying the database unnecessarily even if data hasn't changed.
2. Suppose I have implemented some sort of pagination and I want to exploit the fact that most users would only visit first few pages before going to a different link. I could statically pre render first 1000 pages, so the most visited pages are served statically without going to the database whereas the rest are server side rendered. Now, if my data *might* change frequently, I would have to re render the first 1000 pages after regular intervals and each page would issue a *separate* query against the same database or external API which would cause too many round trips. I am not aware of the details of Nextjs but I suspect this would be true because Nextjs does not assume anything about the function which pulls the data and a generic implementation would necessitate it.

#### Attempted Solution

1. Both problems can be solved by client or server side rendering because the data would be fetched on demand but we lose the benefits of static generation specifically serving static assets compared to querying the database. I believe static generation would be useful if mutations to my data happen infrequently *most of the time* but we still want to show the updated information as fast as we can when it becomes available.
2. If I forget about Nextjs for a a while, both problems can be solved by spawning a new process which listens for mutations to the relevant data and only rebuilds those static assets which needs to be updated; kind of like React updates components but on server side. However Nextjs offers a lot of functionalities which would be difficult to replicate, so I cannot use this approach.
3. If I want to use Nextjs, problem (1) seems impossible to solve due to (perceived?) limitation of Nextjs which only offers one way to rebuild static pages, periodically re render them after a predetermined time. However, (2) can be solved by using some sort of in memory cache which pulls all the required data from the data store in one round trip and structures it up for every page. Then every page will pull data from this cache instead of the database. However, it looks like a hack to me.

#### Questions

1. Are there other ways to deal with the problem I might have have missed?
2. Is there a built-in way to deal with problem (1) and (2) in Nextjs?
3. Is my assessment of attempted solutions and their viability correct?

Comment: Did you get to any resolution, findings, learnings or decisions? Happy to connect to help

Comment: @diegoaguilar

No, I didn't. Would love help in any form.

Comment: I made it work decently enough with GQL (my data source supports it), ISR and a few simple Redis structures.


I still try to keep it simple, but most of my issues came after my data source GQL schema didn't allow some links in content to generate certain paths and its props.

ALSO, fallback helps you out like a lot.

So long story short, fallback + ISR is your way.

I'd say, if your data has just a few deletions or these are not strict, build it all first, then rely on fallbacks